# Proof reflexive relation $\{(x,y)\in\{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\} | x-y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: relations

I need to verificate or falsify the relation. In this previouse post ([Showing $ x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$ is an equivalence relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855573/showing-x-y-in-mathbbq-is-an-equivalence-relation)) they just showed that $x\in\mathbb{R}, x-x=0\in\mathbb{Q}$

Does this mean, that I only have to proof that $x\in\mathbb{R}, x-x=0$, which is element of $\mathbb{Z}$? Because I thought that I have to proof it somehow for $(x-y)$, like $(x-y)-(x-y)=0$

Comment: Well, for all $x,y$, $x\sim y$, so trivially, this is a equivalence relation, but its not very interesting.

Comment: $x-x=0$ is enough for proving reflexivity. You also must prove symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: @drhab ah okay, but for example $x+y$ is not reflexive, is it? Because $x+x=0$ is never true?

Comment: $x+y$ on its own is not a relation so cannot carry the label "reflexive". The relation $x+y=0$ is not reflexive unless it is a relation on the set $\{0\}$.

Comment: If  $x,y$ are real, your relation is a little bit more interesting.  Otherwise, it just doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and notation are not very clear.  I will try to restate it in a way that makes more sense to me.

You write:

$\{(x,y)\in\{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\} | x-y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

I interpret $(x,y)\in\{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\}$ to mean  you are taking some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and relating it to some $ y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The condition for this relation is:  $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$

In other words, for integers x and y, we have xRy ("x is related to y") precisely when x - y is an integer.

Now, you want to prove that this relation is reflexive, that is, xRx.

Since x is an integer, you need to check the condition:  $x-x\in\mathbb{Z}$

Since for all integers x, it is true that:  $x-x =0\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the relation is reflexive.

Comment: oh okay, thank you very much! :)